# Deployment of python function to Azure function app

Tags: azure-function-app

However python functions can be deployed from visual studio code to Azure function app, it can't be edited in the portal.

For editing in the portal, i heard that we can use local git deployment. I searched in google but not getting on how to do that deployment.

Can someone please guide me on how to do it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we can just edit azure function(python) in VS code and then deploy it to Azure. I found a [post](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/157) from GitHub which should be the answer of your question.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Hury Shen.